# Как отправить сообщения из Docker контейнера в две сети

Tags: docker, сеть, docker-compose, udp

OC Linux, установлена в VirtualBox.
На физическом хосте имеется два сетевых интерфейса в одной подсети, статика, вот их ip. В VirtualBox я их прокидываю через адаптер в режиме моста.

```
enp0s9
ip = 10.151.68.198

enp0s10
ip = 10.151.68.199
```

Имеется приложение на Java, запущенное в Docker контейнере, которое отправляет сообщения в один из интерфейсов. Протокол UDP, режим multicast

Вот файл docker-compose

```
version: '3.6'
services:
...

  send-eth-four-srv:
    image: ${SERV_IMAGE}
    networks:
      makvlanthree:
        ipv4_address: 10.151.68.211
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: ${SERV_IMAGE_NAME}
    ports:
      - "6004:6001"


networks:
  makvlanthree:
    name: makvlanthree
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp0s9
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "10.151.68.0/24"
          ip_range: "10.151.68.210/29"
          gateway: "10.151.68.1"
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы приложение отправляло сообщения в оба сетевых интерфейса?